# Website Funny On Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, joomla, footer

So I was having a look at my website on my mobile device and there are a few errors I haven't been able to fix. The first is the footer of my site.

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/

[image]

As you can see my footer looks distorted. Any ideas on how to fix it for mobile. This is my css code for the footer.

```
.footer {
background-color: #F6861F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also the other problem is the large amount of white space down the bottom of the page. How would I go about removing that?

Many thanks to whoever can help me sort this problem out.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're setting width by pixels. You cannot expect your website to be responsive if you specify height,width by pixels.

```
.body .container{

width:80%;

}
.navigation .nav-pills{

width:80%;

height:20%;

}
```

That should make your website look more acceptable in mobile view.

**EDIT:**

Add this to your css file.

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
   .body .container{ width:80%; height:100%;}
   .navigation .nav-pills{height:55px;width:100%;}
   .nav > li{float:left;}
   .nav-pills > li a{margin: 10px 10px;}
   .sliderr{height:340px;}
   .footer{margin-top:10%;}
}
```

Try it and let me know if you are happy with it. Also I don't think float left is needed. It's just a habit of mine :X

Comment: Thanks for the help but it made it look worse than before. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I can provide login details if you would like a closer look at my css.

Comment: Hi Jason still doesn't seem to be working for me. Is there another way of doing this? Would you like me to link you my css file so you can have a further look?

Comment: Weird. Could you fiddle it? Anyways you could refer this to understand stuff better. [link](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Not sure what fiddle is sorry mate. But will have a look at link. If you like I can give you my login details if you wanna try it out for yourself? I might have missed something. Cheers.

Comment: Do you have an email i can send it too or can i send it through private message? How do i do that?

Answer (score -1):

this worked out for me, had to go over my entire css a bit and edit, but seemed to work very nicely :)

http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:1em;
    background:#5ee;
}
 #content {
    padding:1em;  
    padding-bottom:5em;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

This works for mobile and webpage, to keep the footer down there.
Doesn't have to be in px, I use em's :) Changed it to em's, this I find better for wwebpage setup :)
Tou can then have other items in absolute position to, just have to be relative to wour Wrapper, the part wich is your entire webpage :)
The body in min-height 100% wont do it, as the body adjust's to the content in the page, and therefore, if less text, it will not stretch out! 
Hope ithis helps you as much as it did me :)

Comment: And remember to includ the "html, body{}", or it wont work :)